# Aligning two raster layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I am teaching myself GIS in baby steps, I recently acquired aerial imagery (employing RGB and NIR-GB sensors) using a small UAV with the intent of generating a map in a small plot of land. After stitching the images, the resulting georeferenced orthomosaics came out misaligned due to the differing GSD (the sensors aren't identical) or slightly different image geotags between flights.

This picture shows the misalignment in question after applying some transparency.

[image: Misalignment]

Is it possible to align and resample both of the layers in QGIS? If so, what procedure can I use to accomplish this task?

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it? I'm having same issue, thanks!